# How to access the embedded struct inside the Slice of Pointers field of a Struct

Tags: go, reflection

I want to add functionality to take the first element when the data is `[]*struct`.

```
func getEncFields(t reflect.Type, list map[string]int) {
    for t.Kind() == reflect.Ptr {
        t = t.Elem()
    }
    if t.Kind() == reflect.Struct {
        for i := 0; i < t.NumField(); i++ {
            field := t.Field(i)
            tag := field.Tag.Get("bson")
            if containsTag(tag, "encr") {
                list[getFieldName(field, tag)]++
            }
            getEncFields(field.Type, list)
        }
    }
```

In this code I need to add functionality when the data is `[]*Struct`. Here is the struct type to be passed in this function.

```
type Customer struct {
    Name     string    `json:"name" bson:"name"`
    Acnumber int64     `json:"acnumber" bson:"acnumber,encr"`
    Number   int64     `json:"number" bson:"number,encr"`
    Address  []*Address `json:"address" bson:"address"`
}
type Address struct {
    Mail string `json:"mail" bson:"mail,encr"`
}
```

Thank you for your support

Comment: "I am new to go lang" then you shouldn't be using `reflect`.  I see you are trying to read the `encr` bson tag, but this seems like an X Y problem.  Why do you want to introspect those tags?  What are you *actually* trying to accomplish?  If just playing with `reflect` to learn the language, I recommend avoiding it until you're fluent in Go.

Comment: `[]*struct` isn't a complete type, and there are no pointers in the type you've shown here. It's not clear what you are actually trying to do. Try creating a [mre] with the input and output you expect.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Drill down through arrays, slices and maps as you do for pointers.

```
func getEncFields(t reflect.Type, list map[string]int) {
    for t.Kind() == reflect.Ptr || t.Kind() == reflect.Slice || t.Kind() == reflect.Array || t.Kind() == reflect.Map {
        t = t.Elem()
    }
    if t.Kind() == reflect.Struct {
        for i := 0; i < t.NumField(); i++ {
            field := t.Field(i)
            tag := field.Tag.Get("bson")
            if containsTag(tag, "encr") {
                list[getFieldName(field, tag)]++
            }
            getEncFields(field.Type, list)
        }
    }
}
```

https://go.dev/play/p/1msFGC89NX-

Comment: This code is working fine. Thank you so much for your support.